# Mysql query to find mobile phone numbers

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a mysql table with a numbers column, this contains a list of UK mobile phone numbers (beginning in 07) and some UK landline numbers (beginning in 01).

How could I query for just the land line numbers?

I know I could use some kind of regex in my application, but if possible I would rather do it using a query.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select * from MyTable where phoneNumber like '01%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Select * from `someTable` where `phoneNumber` like '01%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the Like operator in your query. For example "select number from tbl where number Like '01%'"

Answer (score 0):

Try to read something about the `WHERE` condition and `LIKE` comparison.

For example here: [The SQL LIKE Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Comment: A good suggestion, but doesn't really provide an answer to the question.

Comment: like the request didn't show any attempt to solve the problem :)

Comment: This was very useful, as where all the examples! Much appreciated